# Resolve ambiguity from grammar for C initialization list

Tags: bison, context-free-grammar, shift-reduce-conflict, ambiguous-grammar

I cannot seem to resolve the ambiguity contained in the following rule:

**InitializerList_a →,[Initializer][InitializerList_a]**

It is causing a shift/reduce conflict in my parser (I'm using Bison). The following is its closure:

```
InitializerList_a → ε

Initializer → [Constant]

Initializer → {[InitializerList][Initializer_a]

Initializer_a → }

Initializer_a → ,}

InitializerList → [Initializer][InitializerList_a]
```

Any help would be appreciated. I can post the bison output file if needed.

Here is the same grammar written in a more readable way:

```
L → IT

T → ,IT | ε

I → [Constant] | {LA

A → } | ,}

where [Constant] is a terminal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should cover it. YACC like grammars prefer head recursion over tail recursion in the grammar.

```
%start I
%token CONSTANT
%%
I: CONSTANT | '{' L '}' ;
L: J | J ',' ;
J: I | J ',' I ;
```

Comment: Thank you but which non-terminal from the original grammar does J correspond to? Or is it a new non-terminal?

Comment: Probably `T`. I was just winging it.

Comment: this isn't correct.. could you try again? The grammar is for the initilization of a variable/array. 
e.g. i = 1 or i = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }

Comment: Oh my apologies. I thought it wouldn't work because you didn't use one of the original non-terminals but I guess that doesn't matter. It works. Thanks!